Unable to connect to Progress AdminServer
The broker has suddenly stopped communicating between linux server and windows server after a recent linux suse upgrade. It looks like its not even searching the broker(Searching broker never comes while running commands) and it times out after 4 mins giving unable to connect/find broker. Have tried all possible options like check admin server logs broker logs but no trace of issue found
Note: Port 20931 telnet command works with win server
Progress Version: 11.3.2
Connecting to Progress AdminServer using rmi://(win_server):20931/Chimera (8280)
Unable to connect to (broker_name)(8289)
Unable to find (broker_name)(8281)


Did the version of Java change when you upgraded Linux?

Check adminserver log files. Also make sure that it indeed is the adminserver running on that port and not something else.

No change in Java version. Also the issue started happening after 2-3 weeks of upgrade so doesnt look related.

proadsv -query
OpenEdge Release 11.3.2 as of Mon Jan 27 16:30:16 EST 2014
AdminServer is alive. (8545)

The error seems to indicate you try to connect to the windows server, not to the linux. You may be looking at the wrong server
